# Rise Up - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Some want me high, others low.
But always upwards do I go.
Quickly or slow, large or small.
It is often me you will call.

In the end, I alone decide,
Who is happy, and who will hide.
Figure it out, don't play around,
Hurry, before the applause does sound.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are a

> Sports Score

Some want me high, others low.

> Most sports want a high score, but some, like golf have a lower score being superior to a higher one

But always upwards do I go.

> Even in sports where a low score is desired, the score still goes up throughout the game.

Quickly or slow, large or small.

> Some games score frequently (basketball), some rarely (soccer).  Some have very high scores ((American) football), some very low (ice hockey)

It is often me you will call.

> Sports commentators call out the score of the game

In the end, I alone decide,
Who is happy, and who will hide.

> The score determines the winner of the game. The winner is happy, the loser (and their fans) might hide his head in shame

Figure it out, don't play around,
Hurry, before the applause does sound.

> At the end of the game, fans of the game may clap, cheer, or applaud their team.

Comment: Perfectly done!

Comment: I can think of one counterexample to "always upwards do I go".

Comment: @charfellow Darts?

Comment: @feelinferrety Yep! Didn't want to put it in the comments, as it could be a spoiler of sorts.

Comment: @charfellow Ahh, didn't think of darts.

Comment: I kind of feel like once you're in answer territory without scrolling right to the bottom, you're expecting or looking for it. Sorry anyway?

Answer (score 6):

Are you a

> Curtain?

Some want me high, others low.

> I suppose this could just be about how people like their drapes hung.

But always upwards do I go.

> Yeah this is the only one I can't make fit. Curtains do come down.

Quickly or slow, large or small.

> Speed and size of curtains could vary, certainly

It is often me you will call.

> A *curtain call* is what happens at the end of a stage production

In the end, I alone decide,
Who is happy, and who will hide.
Figure it out, don't play around,
Hurry, before the applause does sound.

> People hide behind curtains sometimes—but they also proudly show themselves in front of curtains during the aforementioned curtain call (during and after which there is generally lots of applause)

Comment: @AggieKidd Thought so, just figured the other bits fit well enough that it was worth a try.

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess.  You are ..

> lightning

Some want me high, others low.

> If you are on the ground, you will want it high.  If you are flying, you want to be above it (low).

But always upwards do I go.

> Lightning travels upwards

Quickly or slow, large or small.

> different types of discharges, including ball lightning, which can appear to travel slowly.

It is often me you will call.

> Call lightning to smite your foes

In the end, I alone decide,

> Lightning decision?

Who is happy, and who will hide.

> Some people like thunderstorms, and some try to hide.

Figure it out, don't play around,

> Never play in a lightning storm

Hurry, before the applause does sound.

> The thunderclap that comes with the lightning.